# Using two messaging apps on Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: sms, mms, handcent-sms

I want to use Textra for SMS and Handcent for MMS, because they're both top in each class, respectively. I want to use Textra as if it were the only messaging app. Then when I want to send an MMS, I would open Handcent and sent my picture, video, ect. The problem is when I get any kind of message both apps show a popup and a notification. Textra is set as my default but I'm still getting notifications from Handcent. Can I disable notifications within Handcent and accomplish my goal?

Comment: Which version of Android are you using. SMS handling changed in Kitkat, I think, so you might want to specify if your OS is Kitkat or not.

Comment: Ice Cream Sandwich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, went snooping into Handcent messaging settings and turned off pop up and notifications.

Comment: Glad that you figured it out. Kindly mark your solution as answer.